# English word similar to Greek Kleos?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word in English that conveys the "immortal glory" aspect of [Kleos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleos) as opposed to the "hereditary glory"?

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleos#Plato):

> Diotima ... makes specific references to Alcestis that died to save Admetus, or Achilles to avenge Patroclus, and to Codrus, as examples of heroes in search of fame and **immortal renown**.

(Emphasis mine)

Comment: Fame/infamy carry the connotation, it's often associated with immortality, with having your name known after your death. When you talk about "famous people" it de facto includes dead or alive people.

Comment: Fame indeed seems close, but I was wondering if there is a word meaning "Eternal Fame" with emphasis on eternal? (Similar to what Achilles seems to desire in Illiad)

Comment: Homer too seems to need an adjective to modify *kleos* in order to convey what Thetis has foretold to her son as his reward for fighting and dying at Troy: κλέος ἄφθιτον, *Iliad* 413--not just fame but *imperishable* fame.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe legendary will work for you. Although terribly overused nowadays, it originally meant *told about in a legend* which is essentially immortal renown. The heroes strive to enter the realms of legends.

> legendary :  of, relating to, or characteristic of legend or a legend  [-MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/legendary)
>
> legend : a story from the past that is believed by many people but cannot be proved to be true [-MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/legend)